# I can't get the summary field of a custom content type to appear in the search result

Tags: 8, search

I've been trying to get my custom content type to have its summary field display in my site search. Other content types like articles will display a summary, but my custom one won't. I've checked the search api settings and it displays everything as a listing.

Checking the display fields of the content type (/admin/structure/types/manage/custom-type/display/listing) shows that the summary field is selected as content to display.

Looking at the search api settings (admin/config/search/search-api/index/content/fields) doesn't show anything unusual. The field that I want to appear is listed on this page.

The only thing I could think of is that the search api block (/admin/structure/views/view/search_api) has the show field as a custom rendered entity. I've noticed that if I set the custom rendered entity to display the custom content type as "default" instead of "listing", then it will display everything on that node's page, which isn't very useful. However, it does contain the summary field, so I feel confident the problem does not lie with the summary field.

Comment: Have you configured the **Manage display** tab for the listing view mode?

Comment: Yes, and currently it's set to display the summary. I've tried to have it display other things like the body text just to see if it can display anything, but unfortunately it hasn't allowed me to display anything.

Comment: Turns out it was something hard coded into our site by a group that worked on it previously. It would only recognize fields with a certain name, hence some content types worked while others did not. Sorry about that.